# Out-of-the-box way of storing exceptions caught in a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, exception

Normally, we want to catch apex-side exceptions and throw it gracefully to the lightning component. But my requirement is to catch errors/unhandled scenarios in the lightning component and store those in an `Exception__c` object. Is there an OOTB way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we do not have any out-of-the-box way to store the exception. If you want to do this, then you need to implement the customization with coding.